# Looking for a concise way to check for point collision in a list of Rects

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, pygame, collision-detection, rect

I'm trying to find a way to check if a point lies within any Rect in a list of Rects, and to get the index of that Rect (or the first, if multiple) on the list.

My current solution is to make a single-pixel Rect using the point I want to check for, then using `collidelist` to compare that point against the list I want to search for.

It looks like this:

```
tgtrect = pygame.Rect(coords, (1,1)).collidelist(rectlist)
```

...wherein `coords` is the point checked (usually, not always, a mouse location) and `rectlist` is the list of Rects to be evaluated.
`tgtrect` receives the index number of a colliding Rect, or -1 if there are none.
I need this index value to resolve the identity of the colliding Rect elsewhere.

I feel like there's a better way to get this information (that is, to check `coords` against a list, returning an index (or False/None/-1 if there are no hits), without having to make a Rect each time), but I don't know what it is (or if it exists at all).

Basically, what I need is `<Rect>.collidelist(rectlist)`, but for an (x,y) tuple and not a Rect, or `<Rect>.collidepoint(coords)`, but for a list of Rects and not a single one. (I could use this second method with an iterator for rectlist, but it would be more difficult to get the index for the colliding Rect.)

I looked around a bit and found this,
[Pygame action when mouse 'click' on .rect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150957/pygame-action-when-mouse-click-on-rect), 
which offers a way to check for single Rects, but not a list of many. The significance is that my list of target Rects is dynamic; the number of Rects and their locations changes frequently.

I also read through this,
[Pygame .Rect won't "collide" with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554629/pygame-rect-wont-collide-with-mouse),
which gave a solution that didn't really suit the situation for the same reasons.

Thanks!

((Auth. note: This is my first question, so please forgive me if it's kind of ugly. Please let me know if it does not supply enough information, or there are things I can do to improve it.))

Comment: Please do not use the title to prefix the tag for your question; use the tagging system.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid - I wasn't sure if that was correct or not. Now I know!

Comment: Have a read through the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) which has [information on tagging](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) in addition to lots of other good tips.

Comment: Tagging aside, is it reasonable to ask here if this question is consistent with the guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

I tried to take the relevant code out of broader context to make it more applicable to future situations, but I'm not sure if I went on too long in describing it. Tried my best to fit it onto a single screen.

It feels like a success, since I got exactly the results I needed on the first reply, and almost immediately after asking the question. But still, input is great. Maybe in the form of a private message; I don't know. It's only metarelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple generator expression and [`collidepoint()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint), like

```
>>> rects = [pygame.Rect(0,0,100,100), pygame.Rect(30,30,30,30)]
>>> next((r for r in rects if r.collidepoint(10, 10)), None)
<rect(0, 0, 100, 100)>
>>> next((r for r in rects if r.collidepoint(200, 200)), None)
>>>
```

or, if you really want the index instead of the `Rect` itself:

```
>>> rects = [pygame.Rect(0,0,100,100), pygame.Rect(30,30,30,30)]
>>> next((i for (i, r) in enumerate(rects) if r.collidepoint(10, 10)), -1)
0
>>> next((i for (i, r) in enumerate(rects) if r.collidepoint(100, 200)), -1)
-1
>>>
```

Comment: The second part is exactly what I need; thank you! I was also trying to figure out exactly how `next` worked; this was a huge help.
The specific application of this code is actually with a list of Rect-object pairs. I didn't need an index so much as I needed a way to return the paired element (which I can swap out easily enough for `i` and `enumerate`).